# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server

I don't seem to be able to load the correct drivers for SQL server.

I work with Windows 10, PHP Version 8.2.1

In phpinfo():

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Windows\PHP\php.ini
extension_dir   C:\Windows\PHP\ext
```

in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64.dll
```

But when I look in the `phpinfo()` there is no sqlsrv.

Can anyone help me and tell me what I did wrong? How do I load those drivers?

I already read the post about this error, but none of them offer a solution.

---

I tried PDO.

When I use mysql, I can see it in phpinfo()
But when I try with sql server I get "no value" in the PDO section under PDO drivers.

If I check with "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());", I can see that PDO is loaded.

When I try to connect, I get the message "Connection failed: could not find driver"

Comment: PDO would be a better choice anyway. Does an application you are using require `sqlsrv_*`?

Comment: Did you download the SQL driver and put it in the correct folder...? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Yes I downloaded the drivers and yes they are in the correct folder

Comment: @user3783243 how do I do that?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Comment: How do I load the drivers for SQL Server?